# How can I create a list of blog posts in assemble?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, handlebars.js, assemble

I have got grunt and assemble setup where you can add posts to a posts folder, each post gets assembled and added into /dist/news/ where I can access the list of news items(hopefully?) Currently I can go to my site and visit /news/ and I get a weird directory where I can access the posts but this does not show any styling and I do not know where its coming from:

[image]

The directory has this in my file structure:

```
/dist
 /news/
   first-post.html
   post-two.html
```

When I go to click a link on the above page I can see the post inside this url: http://localhost:9000/news/first-post.html

What I want to do is try and replicate this on my template pages but I cannot find the page at all to style or grab the code from. Here is my setup so far:

**Gruntfile.js**

```
assemble: {
      options: {
        collections: [
          {
            name: 'navMain',
            sortby: 'number',
            sortorder: 'ascending' 
          },
          {
            name: 'posts',
            sortby: 'posted',
            sortorder: 'descending'
          },
          {
            name: 'footerNav',
            sortby: 'name',
            sortorder: 'ascending'
          }
        ]

      },
      pages: {
        options: {
          flatten: true,
          assets: '<%= config.dist %>/assets',
          layout: '<%= config.src %>/templates/layouts/default.hbs',
          data: '<%= config.src %>/data/*.{json,yml}',
          partials: '<%= config.src %>/templates/partials/*.hbs'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= config.dist %>/': ['<%= config.src %>/templates/pages/*.hbs']
        }
      },
      misc: {
        files: {
          '<%= config.dist %>/': ['<%= config.src %>/templates/misc/*.hbs']
        }
      },
      blog: {
        options: {
          flatten: true,
          assets: '<%= config.dist %>/assets',
          layout: '<%= config.src %>/templates/layouts/default.hbs',
          data: '<%= config.src %>/data/*.{json,yml}',
          partials: '<%= config.src %>/templates/partials/*.hbs',
          collections: [{name: 'posts', inflection: 'post'}]
        },
        files: {
            '<%= config.dist %>/news/': ['<%= config.src %>/templates/posts/*.hbs']
        }
      },
    }
```

Then in each post located inside:

```
/src/templates/posts
  first-post.md
```

I have this inside it with YAML for data:

```
---
title: this post
posts:
 - news
posted: 2014-10-01
author: James
---
{{title}}
```

This is all fine but I really need this to work better and I need to be able to show these in a list in various places not just limited to the above picture I added.

Can someone shed some light into this a little please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your web server is providing a default index page for `/news/` based on the file structure.  A custom index list of your posts might look something like this:

```
<h1>News Index</h1>
<div>
    {{#each posts}}
        {{#is post "news"}}
            {{#withSort pages "data.posted" dir="desc"}}
                <div>
                    <h2><a href="/{{relativeLink}}">{{data.title}}</a></h2>
                    <p>By {{data.author}} on {{data.posted}}</p>
                    <p><a href="/{{relativeLink}}">more...</a></p>
                </div>
            {{/withSort}}
        {{/is}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

I've written about [building a blog with Assemble](http://opsbynumbers.com/2014/10/28/learning-assemble-step-6-blogging-with-markdown/), that might be helpful to you.

Comment: Hey James, yeah tried following that but its not working. The above does not work too :(

Comment: Could it be my gruntfile playing up?

Comment: Is your index page part of the `blog` target in your gruntfile?  What does happen, does the page get generated, are there no post links, etc.?

Comment: No I don't think so the gruntfile is what you see above. When I save a post in /posts it gets created and put in /dist/news/ then on the site I can view each post on /news/news-title.html so all is created just the list cannot be generated...its an odd situation

Comment: The index page needs to be part of the same target to have access to the post data.

Comment: How do I add that to the assemble grunt js file? Is that in the options for my posts?

Comment: Your grunt.js defines three targets for Assemble: 1.) a **pages** target that applies to templates under `templates/pages/*.hbs`, 2.) **misc** target for `templates/misc/*.hbs`, and 3.) **posts** target for `templates/misc/*.hbs` files.  These targets do not share data. Only templates processed as part of the **posts** target will have access to metadata about your posts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78447/discussion-between-m-dunbavan-and-james-wing).